# Simple multithreading Delphi

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I am still quite new to threading.  I want to create a procedure which tests for a valid internet connection while the main thread creates the necessary forms.  The code snippet stops at the end of the constructor with a 'Cannot call Start on a running or suspended thread' error.  And for some reason the main form is closed after this error

```
constructor TPingThread.Create(IDThread: Integer);
begin
  Self.FID:=IDThread;
  Self.FreeOnTerminate:=true;
end;

destructor TPingThread.Destroy;
begin
  EndThread(FID);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TPingThread.Execute;
var
  iTimeOuts, K: Byte;
  sWebpage: String;
begin
  inherited;
  iTimeOuts:=0;
  FIdPing:=TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  for k:=1 to 3 do
    begin
      Try
        FIdPing.ConnectTimeout:=2000;
        sWebpage:=FIdPing.Get('http://www.google.co.za')
      Except
        On Exception do inc(iTimeOuts);
      End;
    end;
  if iTimeOuts=3 then MessageDlg('A working internetconnection is needed to reset your password',mtWarning,[mbOK],0);
  if iTimeOuts=0 then FInternetConnection:=false
  else FInternetConnection:=true;
  FreeAndNil(FIdPing);
end;
```

Comment: You forgot to call `inherited` in your constructor.

Comment: And don't call inherited in Execute.

Comment: That yields an Incompatible types error

Comment: Inherited Create(false); // Run the thread

Comment: Yes, because there is no constructor that would accept integer parameter. To be more specific, call either `inherited Create;` if you want to create a running thread, or `inherited Create(True);` if you want a suspended one.

Comment: @Marnu123 Incompatible types because your constructor is an overload. You have to call the base constructor - `inherited Create(true)` to create the thread suspended

Comment: It seems to be working now.  Thanks a million!

Comment: Calling (System.)EndThread in the destructor is not necessary, TThread will do this for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some problems with your code:

1. You need to call the `inherited` constructor:

   ```
   constructor TPingThread.Create(IDThread: Integer);
   begin
     inherited Create(false); // Or true to create a suspended thread
     Self.FID:=IDThread;
     ...
   ```
2. Remove the `inherited` call in the `Execute` method, since this is an abstract declaration of `TThread`. Not an error per se, but should be avoided for clarity.
3. Use a try/finally after creating `FIdPing` in the Execute method.
4. As @mjn says, there is no need to call `EndThread()`, since the `TThread` handles this for you.
5. Calling the VCL `MessageDlg()` from a thread is not thread safe. You need to synchronize the call or use the `Application.MessageBox`, a Delphi wrapper to windows `MessageBox`. Best solution would be to skip the dialog and pass an error message to the main thread, which would need to know this error anyway.

Comment: I'm personally removing `inherited` calls of abstract methods (even though the IDE generates it), but will that actually hurt something ?

Comment: @TLama, perhaps I'm wrong, but a call to an abstract method should give a `EAbstractError` or something like that.

Comment: @TLama, the compiler checks that an inherited call is valid when you just call `inherited`.

Comment: @LURD, and doesn't care to check that if you explicitly write `inherited Execute;` (at least in Delphi XE3). I'll keep removing any `inherited` calls of abstract methods from the generated class skeletons.

Comment: @TLama, if the method was a function, `Result := inherited` would have caused an exception. I always throw away abstract methods as well.